# <br> Tag parsing using python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to golf course extract data from a given website in which it will create a CSV that contains the name and address. For the address though the website where I am taking the data from has 
 tag breaking it apart. Is it possible to parse out the two address which is break apart by a 
 into two separate columns?

SO it it looks like this on the HTML

```
<div class="location">10799 E 550 S<br>Zionsville, Indiana, United States</div>
```

I want that it will be broken into

```
Column1:10799 E 550 S
Column2:Zionsville, Indiana, United States
```

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

courses_list = []

with open('Garmin_GC.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for i in range(3):  #893
        url = "http://sites.garmin.com/clsearch/courses/search?course=&location=&country=US&state=&holes=&radius=&lang=en&search_submitted=1&per_page={}".format(
            i * 20)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
        g_data2 = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result"})
        for item in g_data2:
            try:
                name = item.find_all("div", {"class": "name"})[0].text
            except IndexError:
                name = ''
                print "No Name found!"
            try:    
                address = item.find_all("div", {"class": "location"})[0].get_text(separator=' ')
                print address
            except IndexError:
                address = ''
                print "No Address found!"
            writer.writerow([name.encode("utf-8"), address.encode("utf-8")])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.stripped_strings` generator](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
address = list(item.find('div', class_='location').stripped_strings)
```

This'll produce a list of two strings:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> markup = '''<div class="location">10799 E 550 S<br>Zionsville, Indiana, United States</div>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
>>> list(soup.find('div', class_='location').stripped_strings)
[u'10799 E 550 S', u'Zionsville, Indiana, United States']
```

Putting that in the context of your code:

```
try:
    name = item.find('div', class_='name').text
except AttributeError:
    name = u''
try:
    address = list(item.find('div', class_='location').stripped_strings)
except AttributeError:
    address = [u'', u'']
writer.writerow([v.encode("utf-8") for v in [name] + address])
```

where the two address values are written to two separate columns.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode' I am getting this error. Can you help me with that

Comment: @Gonzalo68: you now have a list with unicode strings. Encode the contents of the list, not the list itself.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: i am getting an invalid Syntax Error. :(

Comment: @Gonzalo68: yes, a `]` closing bracket was missing, added now.